# Multidimensional (sublist to list) assignment

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2-dimensional list of integers, and I want to assign respectively a smaller 2-dimensional list into the first list. I mean if the first list *a* is like this:

> [[2, **2**, **2**, **2**]
>   ,[2, **2**, **2**, **2**]
>   ,[2, 2, 2, 2]]

and I want to assign this list

> [[1,1,1]
>   ,[1,1,1]] (actually [[1]*3]*2)

to the first list *a* at the position [0:2][1:4] then it should become

> [[2, **1**, **1**, **1**]
>   ,[2, **1**, **1**, **1**]
>   ,[2, 2, 2, 2]]

I'm currently using this piece of code

```
for i in range(0,2):
    a[i][1:4]=[1]*3
```

,which use 1-dimensional shallow-copy [?:?] list assignment.
So is there any way to get a sub-2-dimensional-list, like a[i:y][j:z] ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the issue with using a for loop?

Comment: @Josh: Same reason we prefer slice assignment to a `for` loop for 1-dimensional operations; slicing is shorter, easier to get right, and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do that with Python lists. Lists are fundamentally oriented around 1-dimensional operations. [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays have great support for all sorts of multidimensional manipulation, though. With arrays, you could do

```
a[:2, 1:] = 1
```

and assign the number 1 to all positions in a multidimensional subarray. If you're doing a lot of array operations, check it out.

Comment: Wow, so fast a response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your own function for it if you're looking for neatness of code?

```
def set_items(arr, val, x_lims, y_lims):
    for i in range(x_lims[0], x_lims[1]):
        arr[i][y_lims[0]:y_lims[1]] = val

set_items(a, [1]*3, [0, 2], [1, 4])
```